# Does a non-creature God entering the battlefield trigger Pelt Collector?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I have a 1/1 [Pelt Collector](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPelt%20Collector%5d) on the battlefield, then cast [Nylea, Keen-Eyed](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNylea%2c%20Keen-Eyed%5d). I don't have enough devotion to turn Nylea into a creature. Does Pelt Collector, which triggers when a creature with more power enters the battlefield, trigger?

I'm guessing no because Nylea isn't a creature, but I'm not sure. After all, it's also a creature spell when it's being cast. If it enters the battlefield as a creature before becoming an enchantment, presumably Pelt Collector will trigger.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Pulling from a ruling on [Nylea, God of the Hunt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNylea%2c%20God%20of%20the%20Hunt%5d):

> When a God enters the battlefield, your devotion to its color
>   (including the mana symbols in the mana cost of the God itself) will
>   determine if a creature entered the battlefield or not for abilities
>   that trigger whenever a creature enters the battlefield.

So if you don't have enough devotion for Nylea to be a creature, it doesn't trigger Pelt Collector.

Comment: Moral of the story, read the rulings!

Answer (score 8):

**No, if you don't have enough Devotion, Nylea enters the battlefield only as an enchantment. Abilities that care about Nylea being a creature have no effect.**

Nylea's ability that removes its creature type is a static ability:

> 604.1. Static abilities do something all the time rather than being activated or triggered. They are written as statements, and they’re simply true.

At the moment when Nylea enters the battlefield, if your devotion including the +1 from Nylea itself is less than five, the ability's conditon is true, and thus removes all creature-related characteristics (creature type, God subtype, power, toughness) from that object.

There is no triggered ability to mark this change, it's true as soon as Nylea enters the battlefield. Therefore, without sufficient devotion, the game never sees an "enchantment creature Nylea" entering the battlefield, only an "enchantment Nylea".

For example, [Darkest Hour](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDarkest%20Hour%5d) causes all creatures to enter the battlefield as black creatures and to trigger [Dire Undercurrents](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDire%20Undercurrents%5d), no matter what color they would have without Darkest Hour.

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that the reason Nylea is a creature spell on the stack is because the "as long as" clause prevents it from being a characteristic-defining ability (604.3a). Otherwise it would apply in all zones and outside the game (604.3), and you'd be able to fetch it with Fae of Wishes.